# Attempting to find the closest point to the middle of the screen, from a list of points

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying the find the closest coordinate to 840, 525 in the generated list keypoints.

Background:
I'v been working on a system to move a blob(OpenCV gives a coordinate for the centre of each) in the centre of a screen to another blob somewhere else, there are multiple generated blobs at one time, but i want to go to the closest blob from my position in the middle(840, 525). The blobs are found by OpenCV. The moment is controlled by my mouse as the middle blob moves to the coordinates of my mouse pointer.

Currently its just putting the curser on the first point it finds.

```
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)

# Detect blobs.
keypoints = detector.detect(processed_img)

#put curser on top of blob
win32api.SetCursorPos((int(keypoints[0].pt[0]),(int(keypoints[0].pt[1]))))

# Draw detected blobs as red circles.
# cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS ensures the size of the circle corresponds to the size of blob
processed_img = cv2.drawKeypoints(processed_img, keypoints, np.array([]), (255, 0, 0), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
```

Okay, so OpenCV gives me a big list or array? of points which i then covert to pixel coordinates. I'm not sure how to search the list or array for the closet one to the middle which is (840, 525).

Thanks, its not like VisualBasic where i can loop though every one to find the closest :(

Comment: When you say "the closest blob" to some pixel, this could mean a few different things. Blobs are made of many pixels; do you want to measure from something like the center of the blob, or from the closest pixel on the edge of the blob to that point? Also: "its not like VisualBasic where i can loop though every one to find the closest" you *definitely can* do that in basically every programming language, including Python...

Comment: I'l edit my post, OpenCV finds the centre of the blob and gives a single coordinate value for it. I could loop though the list if i knew how to. I know how to split x and y but I'm not sure how to search more values then the first one.

Comment: Can you edit to give a [*minimal* and *complete* verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? In particular with an example processed image and what precisely you want to happen? As it stands, no one can copy/paste this code and run it and give you an answer. I also don't really understand what you're asking here. What does it mean to "move a blob to another blob"? What does "the moment is controlled by my mouse" mean?

Comment: I'm trying the find the closest coordinate to 840, 525 in the generated list keypoints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual pixel positions of a `keypoint` object in OpenCV can be grabbed from the `.pt` attribute of the keypoint.

For example, after detecting keypoints in an image, then printing the coordinates of the first keypoint would look like:

```
>>> keypoints[0].pt
(100.80000305175781, 100.80000305175781)
```

What you want to be able to do is grab the closest keypoint to some specified position. There are two really simple ways of doing that using Python built-ins. The `min()` and `sorted()` functions both accept a `key` argument used to create the numbers to compare---you'd want the distance between each keypoint and your set point. If you did `sorted()` you'd get all the keypoints ordered by smallest distance, if you did `min()` of course you'd just get the one smallest (and it would be faster).

Say you want to detect the closest keypoint to the set point (10, 20) (here using (x, y) ordering). You can simply do:

```
>>> pt = np.array([10, 20])
>>> nearest_kp = min(keypoints, key=lambda kp: np.linalg.norm(kp.pt - pt))
>>> nearest_kp.pt
(100.22400665283203, 100.22400665283203)
```

Note that the returned value here is still a keypoint, so the actual location of it still needs to be grabbed with the `.pt` attribute.

Comment: YOUR AMAZING! Iv been working on this for the last 2 days, its so simple and works very well. I just replaced 10, 20 with 840, 525 like you said and it works. I marked it as solved.

Comment: @jacksalssome The annoying thing here is just that the `keypoints` are a list of *objects* but it's not well documented for Python, so it's hard to know how to get the actual points out. For future reference, if you use the Python function `dir()` on an object you can see the available methods and attributes. For e.g. in answering your question, I forgot whether the attribute was `.pt` or `.point`, so I did `dir(keypoints[0])` to see all the available methods and attributes. This comes in handy for other objects as well, so keep it in the back of your mind :)

Comment: Okay i'l do that, yeah there's no documentation on it at all.